# YA novel - set in an orphanage - spiny fish fed blood and candle wax

Tags: story-identification

I am trying to identify the title and author of a young adult novel I encountered as a teen, around the mid to late 90s. It was:

- A Gothic horror/fantasy
- Took place in an orphanage

and the major scenes I recall are:

- The young protagonists finding a bizarre spiny fish washed up near their orphanage.
- Later the same fish being fed candle wax and blood by one of the
  stories villains.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Around when did you read this book? 80s, 90s, 00s?

Comment: This would have been mid to late nineties.